# Alternative to for() function when it comes to saving variables?

Tags: r

So I have data that looks like this:

```
Merged[[1]]
Date   A   B   C
01/01  1   2   3

Merged[[2]]
Date   B1   B2  B3
01/01  4    5   6
```

And so on. I want to save a new variable, Merged2, using specific indices for MergedData such that:

```
Merged2 <- 0
for (i in sig){
  Merged2 <- Merged[[i]]
  FileName <- paste("Merged2",".csv", sep="")
  write.csv(Merged2, file=FileName)
}
```

But unsurprisingly, this only saves the the very last i in sig. I've also tried:

```
Merged2 <- 0
for (i in sig){
Merged2 <- Merged2[c(1, Merged[[i]])]
}
```

But then it returns Error in TrendData[c(1, MergedData[[i]])] : invalid subscript type 'list'.

Is there an alternative way to do this rather than relying on a for() function?

Comment: You're naming every file "Merged2.csv" and overwriting it many times.

Comment: `paste0("Merged2",sig,".csv")` or something similar could be used to differentiate the parts.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Ah, I see. So I should have it outside the for() function. Also, noted. I'll remove the link.

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks, I've tried assigning Merged2 to 0 and then assigned it to Merged2[c(1, MergedData[[i]]), but that didn't seem to work. Is this what you were suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

You could vectorize most of the work, then just use a loop to create the files. Without any data to go on here we go ...

```
## subset the Merged list by sig to get new list
Merged2 <- Merged[sig]
## create the file names
Filenames <- paste0("Merged2", sig, ".csv")
## here is the multivariate loop that creates the files
Map(write.csv, x = Merged2, file = Filenames)
```

Output to the console will be a list of NULLs, which is expected.  You can use `list.files()` to check that the files exist.